# Scylla DB: SELECT (*) times out on empty table

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have a table that used to have lots of data but this data died due to ttl long time ago.

But when I run queries such as `SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10` or `SELECT count(*) FROM my_table` runs out of few-second timeout.

When I read the data using spark-cassandra-connector (which queries the table by token ranges internally) it takes few minutes to actually get 0 entries.

I suspected that something is wrong with compaction and tombstones are not deleted but table data directory doesn't look huge:

> /var/lib/scylla$ sudo ls -la
>
> /data/scylla/data/my_space/my_table-75f8388035c211e9bc85000000000011
>
> total 2604 drwx------   4 scylla scylla   8192 Nov 27 15:55 .
>
> drwx------ 215 scylla scylla  16384 Nov 15 19:00 ..
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    538 Nov 25 22:58 mc-1552402-big-CompressionInfo.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla 162869 Nov 25 22:58 mc-1552402-big-Data.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     10 Nov 25 22:58 mc-1552402-big-Digest.crc32
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    656 Nov 25 22:58 mc-1552402-big-Filter.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla  72244 Nov 25 22:58 mc-1552402-big-Index.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     54 Nov 25 22:58 mc-1552402-big-Scylla.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   6234 Nov 25 22:58 mc-1552402-big-Statistics.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    176 Nov 25 22:58 mc-1552402-big-Summary.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    102 Nov 25 22:58 mc-1552402-big-TOC.txt
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    474 Nov 25 22:38 mc-1578193-big-CompressionInfo.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla 135730 Nov 25 22:38 mc-1578193-big-Data.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     10 Nov 25 22:38 mc-1578193-big-Digest.crc32
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    496 Nov 25 22:38 mc-1578193-big-Filter.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla  67215 Nov 25 22:38 mc-1578193-big-Index.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     54 Nov 25 22:38 mc-1578193-big-Scylla.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   6234 Nov 25 22:38 mc-1578193-big-Statistics.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    148 Nov 25 22:38 mc-1578193-big-Summary.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    102 Nov 25 22:38 mc-1578193-big-TOC.txt
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    202 Nov 25 23:12 mc-1582107-big-CompressionInfo.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla  49607 Nov 25 23:12 mc-1582107-big-Data.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     10 Nov 25 23:12 mc-1582107-big-Digest.crc32
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    176 Nov 25 23:12 mc-1582107-big-Filter.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla  24733 Nov 25 23:12 mc-1582107-big-Index.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     54 Nov 25 23:12 mc-1582107-big-Scylla.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   6234 Nov 25 23:12 mc-1582107-big-Statistics.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     92 Nov 25 23:12 mc-1582107-big-Summary.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    102 Nov 25 23:12 mc-1582107-big-TOC.txt
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   1826 Nov 25 22:39 mc-1601869-big-CompressionInfo.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla 639833 Nov 25 22:39 mc-1601869-big-Data.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     10 Nov 25 22:39 mc-1601869-big-Digest.crc32
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   2096 Nov 25 22:39 mc-1601869-big-Filter.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla 251799 Nov 25 22:39 mc-1601869-big-Index.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     98 Nov 25 22:39 mc-1601869-big-Scylla.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   6234 Nov 25 22:39 mc-1601869-big-Statistics.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    428 Nov 25 22:39 mc-1601869-big-Summary.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    102 Nov 25 22:39 mc-1601869-big-TOC.txt
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    514 Nov 25 23:40 mc-1664251-big-CompressionInfo.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla 146270 Nov 25 23:40 mc-1664251-big-Data.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     10 Nov 25 23:40 mc-1664251-big-Digest.crc32
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    496 Nov 25 23:40 mc-1664251-big-Filter.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla  69800 Nov 25 23:40 mc-1664251-big-Index.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     54 Nov 25 23:40 mc-1664251-big-Scylla.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   6234 Nov 25 23:40 mc-1664251-big-Statistics.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    148 Nov 25 23:40 mc-1664251-big-Summary.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    102 Nov 25 23:40 mc-1664251-big-TOC.txt
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    522 Nov 25 23:39 mc-1679659-big-CompressionInfo.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla 147350 Nov 25 23:39 mc-1679659-big-Data.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla      9 Nov 25 23:39 mc-1679659-big-Digest.crc32
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    496 Nov 25 23:39 mc-1679659-big-Filter.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla  70504 Nov 25 23:39 mc-1679659-big-Index.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     54 Nov 25 23:39 mc-1679659-big-Scylla.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   6234 Nov 25 23:39 mc-1679659-big-Statistics.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    148 Nov 25 23:39 mc-1679659-big-Summary.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    102 Nov 25 23:39 mc-1679659-big-TOC.txt
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    562 Nov 25 23:05 mc-1742082-big-CompressionInfo.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla 181106 Nov 25 23:05 mc-1742082-big-Data.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla      8 Nov 25 23:05 mc-1742082-big-Digest.crc32
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    656 Nov 25 23:05 mc-1742082-big-Filter.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla  69320 Nov 25 23:05 mc-1742082-big-Index.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     54 Nov 25 23:05 mc-1742082-big-Scylla.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   6234 Nov 25 23:05 mc-1742082-big-Statistics.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    176 Nov 25 23:05 mc-1742082-big-Summary.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    102 Nov 25 23:05 mc-1742082-big-TOC.txt
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    554 Nov 25 23:24 mc-1774537-big-CompressionInfo.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla 176335 Nov 25 23:24 mc-1774537-big-Data.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla      9 Nov 25 23:24 mc-1774537-big-Digest.crc32
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    656 Nov 25 23:24 mc-1774537-big-Filter.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla  67974 Nov 25 23:24 mc-1774537-big-Index.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla     54 Nov 25 23:24 mc-1774537-big-Scylla.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla   6234 Nov 25 23:24 mc-1774537-big-Statistics.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    176 Nov 25 23:24 mc-1774537-big-Summary.db
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 scylla scylla    102 Nov 25 23:24 mc-1774537-big-TOC.txt drwx------   2 scylla scylla      6 Feb 21 
>   2019 staging drwx------   2 scylla scylla      6 Feb 21  2019 upload

Modification times are quite fresh so probably some compaction actually happened.

My table config:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    f1 uuid,
    f2 tinyint,
    c boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (f1, f2)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (f1 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

1. Do you see any load to CPU, IO, Network while having these long CQL executing? see https://docs.scylladb.com/troubleshooting/report_scylla_problem/#report-a-performance-problem
2. You can compare stats from `nodetool cfstats` https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/nodetool-commands/cfstats/ to check known table size and avg of tombstones to what you see on disk.
3. You can try to enable tracing for the query and take a look at how your query is executing. Is there a normal executing plan? What steps are slow? How many partitions/nodes does it touch?
4. Mainly this [How to get tombstone count for a cql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063508/how-to-get-tombstone-count-for-a-cql-query) says that having run a query with tracing you can see how many total reads the query performed and how many tombstones were there.

You will be able to move from there considering the results.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, will try on Monday

Comment: The problem just gone. Thanks anyways)

Answer (score 5):

Tombstones are kept alive for `gc_grace_period` which is 10 days by default. This is to prevent data resurrection, that is to assure each node that has data falling under the tombstones receive that tombstone (via repair).

Your query is probably reading through thousands of tombstones, not finding anything to return.

Comment: The problem just gone. Thanks for suggestion.